# Looping a substr function with start and stop argumets stored in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large and messy character vector `html`.
I also have a data frame `url_characters`:

```
  start   end
1 35288 35333
2 36723 36768
3 38168 38213
4 39647 39692
5 41091 41136
6 42549 42594
```

How can I create a loop in R that would perform substr function on character vector `html` using each row of the data frame for start and end arguments and store the results in a new character vector with each extraction as a separate item of the vector?
I am an absolute beginner so pardon me if the solution is an obvious one or already exists somewhere, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you please include an example of the output you hope to achieve. There does not seem to be enough information in your question to help you. Have you looked at [MRE]?

Comment: You could try `mapply(function(x, y) substr(html, x, y - x), url_characters$start, url_characters$stop)`

Comment: @AllanCameron
With a little tweaking I've managed to achieve desired results. The code that did the work for me was: `mapply(function(x, y) substr(html, x, y), url_characters$start, url_characters$end)`
I need to brush up on my mapply function. Other than ?help do you have any particular good resources to recommend?
Thanks a lot!